# Word for someone trying doggedly to befriend someone

Tags: word-choice

How is called this word when someone is trying doggedly to be a friend of someone especially when their efforts is annoying?

Tell me please what verb, adjective or adverb I can use to mean someone is constantly trying to become a friend of someone and that someone doesn't really want to see that person in their circle.

Comment: There is no verb that means "to make repeated unsuccessful attempts to join a circle of friends". Are you looking perhaps for an adverb or an adjective to describe such a person or such attempts?

Comment: If you provide an example sentence of how you might like to use that word, it might be easier for us to find the right one.

Comment: This question has already produced a series of "random" answers. You need to provide more focus in order to help us determine a *particular* word that matches what you are looking for. Questions shouldn't be used to simply ask for a list of synonyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for something to describe the person, there are:

- **importunate** mentioned by Tᴚoɯɐuo (annoyingly persistent in solicitation) seems to capture the description
- **bothersome** (causing annoyance)
- **can't take a hint** (slang)
- **clueless** (slang; the person doesn't have a clue that they are unwanted)
- **wannabe** member (slang, derived from "want to be";  a person who wants or aspires to be someone or something else)

Regarding their action:

- to persistently do something to someone else that is undesired is to **harass** (various forms for different parts of speech)

Comment: My upvote is mostly for _can't take a hint_, which is a very apt expression in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

To bother someone repeatedly about something is to **badger** them.  **Badgering** doesn't specifically involve attempts to join a group, however, though it can apply to such a situation.

A person who is persistently annoying or intrusive in their ways can be called **importunate** or **pushy**.

A person who doesn't take a hint that they're not wanted can be called an **intruder**.  A person who breaks into your house to commit harm or theft can also be called an intruder.

Comment: For a person who persists despite all, **stalker** is better than **intruder**.

Comment: I think **stalker** is an extreme case, as you said, "despite *all*".  You can be intrusive or pushy or obtuse without being a stalker. *stalker* implies something *menacing*.

Comment: +1 for importunate

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for adverbs and adjectives that describe something like "to make repeated unsuccessful attempts" and is also annoying at the same time, you could go work with any of these:

- **Hound** (verb): harass, persecute, or pursue relentlessly. To hound someone is to relentlessly pursue or pester them. However, a person who wants to be your friend is unlikely to hound you. This is on the extreme side.
- **Incessant** (adj): (of something regarded as unpleasant) continuing without pause or interruption.
- **Pester** (verb): trouble or annoy (someone) with frequent or persistent requests or interruptions. This is perhaps what you are looking for.

I like *badgering* too as mentioned above. Again, without a sentence it is hard to suggest an appropriate word.

Answer (score 1):

People who do not get a message that you do not want to be their friend or let them into your group can be:

- persistent, attempt persistently to be friends, to make persistent attempts
- repeated, that person makes repeated attempts to be friends, to attempt repeatedly to be friends
- annoying, to become annoying by making repeating attempts at friendship, annoyingly attempts or tries to become friends,
- pester, a person pesters you to try and become friends with you
- to make intrusive attempts to become your friend (intrusive here means not recognizing boundaries), to behave intrusively in trying to become friends

Those are some ways you can say it. Of course, there are many others, some of  which are in the first answer. There is also a ton of slang, none of which I am providing here since it seems you want non-slang.